# How do I create a query in Laravel 5.2 query builder, group join

Tags: laravel

I have the following sql PDO query.

```
("SELECT
    actual_remains.quantity,
    ingredients.name,
    ingredients.unit,
    ingredients.id
        FROM
           actual_remains
        LEFT JOIN
    ingredients ON ingredients.id = actual_remains.ingredient
        WHERE
    actual_remains.shop = ".$shopNumber);
```

How would I make this query in laravel query builder?

Comment: Which models have you defined so far? with which relations? can you show those?

Comment: Like to -  DB::table('actual_remains')
                ->select( 'ingredient','quantity')
                ->where('shop', '=', $request)
                ->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the straight Query builder way to write this (See [Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#joins) for more information):

```
$actualRemains = DB::table('actual_remains')
            ->leftJoin('ingredients', 'actual_remains.ingredient', '=', 'ingredients.id')
            ->select('actual_remains.quantity', 'ingredients.name', 'ingredients.unit', 'ingredients.id')
            ->where('actual_remains.shop', '=', $shopNumber)
            ->get();
```

If you create models and set their relationships you will probably have something more like this:

`(new App\ActualRemain)->find($shopNumber)->with('ingredients');`

See [Laravel Docs on relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships) for more information on eloquent relationships.